# Подключение и отключение стилей на определённой странице Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Хочу подключить определённый стиль contact.css к странице контакты и отключить у неё стиль template.css для этого пишу в файле functions.php

```
//отключаем стили к определённой странице
function my_deregister_style () {
    if ( is_page ('14') ) {
        wp_deregister_style ( 'template' );
    }
}
add_action ( 'wp_print_styles', 'my_deregister_style', 100 );

//подключаем стили к определённой странице
 function contact_styles() {
 if ( is_page('14') ) 
 wp_enqueue_style('contact', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/contact.css', array(), '1.0' );
 }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_styles', 'contact_styles' );
```

Но ничего не выходит, подскажите почему?

Comment: Что именно не выходит. И не отключается и не подключается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете не те хуки. Согласно [документации](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_print_styles):

> Since WordPress 3.3 wp_print_styles should not be used to enqueue styles or script

Соответственно следует использовать [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts):

```
function contact_styles() {
    if ( is_page( 14 ) ) {
        //подключаем стили
        wp_enqueue_style ( 'contact', get_template_directory_uri() 
            . '/css/contact.css', array(), '1.0' );
        //отключаем стили
        wp_dequeue_style ( 'template' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'contact_styles' );
```

Это будет работать только если в шаблоне вызывается `wp_head()`. При этом можно решить вашу задачу "костылем". В месте, где в шаблон вставляются стили заменить стиль `template.css` на вот такой кусок кода:

```
<?php
if ( is_page( 14 ) ) {
    $style = 'contact.css';
} else {
    $style = 'template.css';
}
$styleURL = get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/' . $style;
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $styleURL; ?>" />
```

Обращаю внимание - **это плохая практика в WordPress**. Это нарушает единообразие разработки тем и плагинов и усложняет поддержку такого сайта.

Comment: подскажите, как нужно правильно писать и как это будет выглядеть в моём случае. Версия wp 4.4.2

Comment: к сожалению ничего не изменилось (( .Такое ощущение скрипт ничего не вставляет в страницу.(Если что домен с кириллическими символами)

Comment: ID страницы точно 14? В шаблоне вызывается `wp_head()` или там жестко приписаны стили?

Comment: id точно 14,  в шаблоне в хедере просто линк указан на стиль

Comment: спасибо за помощь, но костыль тоже не работает( Наверное это плохая тема была выбрана

Answer (score 0):

Может глупый вопрос задам, а вы сами стили подключили перед тем как их отключать?))

К примеру:

```
// Load the Internet Explorer specific stylesheet.
wp_enqueue_style( 'twentysixteen-ie', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ie.css', array( 'twentysixteen-style' ), '20160816' );
wp_style_add_data( 'twentysixteen-ie', 'conditional', 'lt IE 10' );
```

Comment: Вопросов глупых не бывает, но для уточнений пользуйтесь комментарием, а не спешите с ответом.

Comment: Пардон) Первый раз здесь)